# mongo-express is not trying to reconnect after first attempt

Tags: docker-compose, mongo-express

I am trying to create two services **mongo** and **mongo-express** through **docker-compose** file.

Let me explain the scenario -
If I run those two containers separately in a same container using docker-run commands in terminal one by one they work fine.

Commands which I ran in terminal ->

For mongo

```
docker run -d \ 
-p27017:27017 \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
--network 6-mar-learning-docker-with-mongo-image \
--name mongodb \
mongo
```

and for mongo-express

```
docker run -d  \
-p 8081:8081 \ 
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password \
--network 6-mar-learning-docker-with-mongo-image \
--name mongo-express \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb \
mongo-express
```

But if I try using docker-compose yaml file **mongo-express** service tries to connect to **mongo** service only once and then exits with code 0.

Here's my yaml file :

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
```

Command I'm using to execute this file

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up
```

Log of this command :

```
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_mongo-express_1 ... done
Creating docker_mongodb_1       ... done
Attaching to docker_mongo-express_1, docker_mongodb_1
mongodb_1        | about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
mongodb_1        | forked process: 32
mongodb_1        | 
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.852+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.856+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.856+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.857+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.857+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.858+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.859+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.859+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.859+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.859+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":32,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"5a9ee157c392"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.860+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.6","gitVersion":"212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.860+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.860+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017,"tls":{"mode":"disabled"}},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/proc/1/fd/1"}}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.861+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:34.861+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=480M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.323+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646573975:323191][32:0x7ff1314c6c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.323+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646573975:323262][32:0x7ff1314c6c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.329+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":468}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.329+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.340+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.340+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.345+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.346+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"admin.system.version","uuidDisposition":"provided","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"6cdf8a79-38eb-4cf7-a722-437bf35ff55f"}},"options":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"6cdf8a79-38eb-4cf7-a722-437bf35ff55f"}}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.354+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"admin.system.version","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":null}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.355+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":20459,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting featureCompatibilityVersion","attr":{"newVersion":"5.0"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.355+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.355+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.355+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.355+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.356+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.356+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"local.startup_log","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"c7bdfd70-ca9a-4a5a-8c7d-b498500fff1f"}},"options":{"capped":true,"size":10485760}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.367+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"local.startup_log","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":null}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.367+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.369+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.369+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.369+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"config.system.sessions","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"a361b644-06c4-4102-8abd-a78af1e4fb4d"}},"options":{}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.369+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.369+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
mongodb_1        | child process started successfully, parent exiting
mongo-express_1  | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express_1  | ------------------------
mongo-express_1  | 
mongo-express_1  | 
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.388+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"_id_","commitTimestamp":null}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.388+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"config.system.sessions","index":"lsidTTLIndex","commitTimestamp":null}}
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongo-express_1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.27.0.3:27017
mongo-express_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
mongo-express_1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
mongo-express_1  | }]
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
mongo-express_1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
mongo-express_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
mongo-express_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.432+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60038","uuid":"70bac03c-a30e-47b6-b6a5-bc6a551ab95e","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.433+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60038","client":"conn1","doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Shell"},"driver":{"name":"MongoDB Internal Client","version":"5.0.6"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"Ubuntu","architecture":"x86_64","version":"20.04"}}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.443+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60038","uuid":"70bac03c-a30e-47b6-b6a5-bc6a551ab95e","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":0}}
docker_mongo-express_1 exited with code 0
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-06T13:39:35.598+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60040","uuid":"2f5cd59e-5691-40c5-a31a-fd4fbb0e6a63","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":1}}
```

`docker ps` output at this instance

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                           NAMES
5a9ee157c392   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   docker_mongodb_1
```

So basically mongo got created and mongo-express did not as it exited.

Now if I press CTRL+C(exiting the command in Mac) after running the **docker-compose** command and run it again. Now it works since **mongo** service is already up and **mongo-express** can establish a connection in the first attempt.

But it should try to reconnect I think, I saw and read a couple of tutorials too which validates that the service should not exit, it should try to reconnect. Maybe I missed something in my **docker-compose.yaml** file, forgive me for that since I'm learning Docker.

Just a small note - I solved this by using/setting the "restart" option to **mongo-express** service, but I've seen in people's tutorials and code that it tries to reconnect itself, without restarting it over and over.

Tutorial reference which I used - https://youtu.be/3c-iBn73dDE?t=5705

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
  mongo-express:
image: mongo-express
ports:
  - 8080:8081
restart: unless-stopped
environment:
  - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
  - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
  - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
```

or any of restart options. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) is the docker docs.
Btw, if you want to use startup-order, I'd recommend you to read [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/containerizing-a-node-js-application-for-development-with-docker-compose) containerize tutorial especially step 4

Ps: I think `version: "3"` is ok, but check the [version capability](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3) before use.
Happy coding:)

Answer (score 1):

The `mongodb` and the `mongo-express` service should not be started at the same time, because the `mongo-express` depends on the `mongodb` container. You can ensure the database running, before the express server starts with the following changes to the compose file.

I have added a simple `healthcheck`, and a `depends_on` there ensure the mongo instance is **healthy** and **ready**, before the express server starts.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo localhost:27017/test --quiet
      retries: 5
      interval: 15s
      start_period: 30s
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: This works, but the answer I'm looking for is why isn't **mongo-express** trying to reconnect on its own in my case. Because in the tutorial which I've mentioned in the question  it's working and it is also recommended in the Docker documentation that this should be implemented - https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ (3rd to 5th paragraph)